# How to make UILabel wordwrap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there anyway of making a UILabel wrap to the next line or do I have to use a UITextView?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would need to set the `numberOfLines` property to `0` and explicitly specify its dimensions, either in IB or programmatically. However, if you have a lot of text to display, I would recommend using a UITextView.

Comment: set `numberOfLines` to `0`, and the `UILabel` will be filled with text, limited by width and height.  it will not create new lines and automatically extend the width/height.  the width/height must be explicity set to accomodate for the size of text

Comment: To adjust the size of the label dynamically, please see my answer and this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796896/662605

Comment: Also gotta set the lineBreakMode property on the UILabel to NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping in Swift and UILineBreakModeWordWrap in Objective-C

Comment: What do you mean explicitly specify its dimensions with IB?  Can I just set the width in the view or do I need to specify something else also?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to adjust your label according to the content's size.

In iOS 6, AutoLayout will work a charm, you should set the label to have `numberOfLines = 0`

In a non AutoLayout scenario, you will also want to make sure the frame of your `UILabel` is adjusted to show the content that's on the next line.

Please check out this answer and sample code for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796896/662605