# Wordwrap text in UILabel with "..." appended at end

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I´v created a custom Cell for a tableview - that has some labels like the original but in the original when the text in the title label is longer than what fit´s on screen it appends "..." at the end. I´ve tried finding ways of doing it in IB with no luck. Do I have to create my own method to get this functionality on the UILabel?

Comment: What does it do when you put a text much larger than it can hold, assuming your label has fixed font size enabled?

Comment: The label has a fixed font size, When I type the text statically in Interface Builder it truncate the tails and add the "...". But in the app - when the table list is populated dynamically it does not truncate the tail adding "..." at the tail

Answer (score 1):

You can use my `UIExtendedLabel` Class From this link(check my ans) [UIExtendedLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868298/how-to-adjust-a-label-size-to-fit-the-length-of-the-text/16869199#16869199)

Answer (score 0):

The default property for numberOfLines on a UILabel is 1, if you want to support a multiline label you need to specify the number of lines.

Such as:

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

You may also need to resize your label to account for the longer text or use a label that will fit the maximum number of lines.

Comment: Or set it to zero and let the label decide.

Comment: I ment that I want the label to append the "..." at end.

Comment: Is your number of lines explicitly set?

Comment: @Anthony number of line is set to 1 in interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I had managed to have two labels on top of each other and did not notice. SO the Label truncates the tail adding "..." automatically at the end if Line break mode is set to truncate tail. My bad - I guess if I were more experienced with iOS programming I should have known it does this automatically