# StackView in stackView does not work with its spacing by swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

In UITableViewCell, I create a vertical stackView.
I add horizontal stackView in the vertical stackView(consists of one UILabel(A) and UIImageView) and a UILabel(B).
I set the spacing is 6 points to all stackViews.
But if the width of UILabel(B) is longer than that of UILabel(A) of horizontal one,
the space expends more than 6 points in horizontal stackView.

How can I solve this problem.

In picture,
above one has a problem that I want to solve(See mute icon is arranged to right to the end of UILabel),
and the bottom one is on correct way.

[image]

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796862/uilabel-auto-size-label-to-fit-text)

Comment: try to fill equally in the horizontal stack view

Answer (score 2):

Take Another Horizontal StackView Add UILable(A) and UILable(B).

Set Alignment and Distribution Property Fill.

Give UILable(B) constraint to trailing space right side.

If problem not solved send storyboard screen shot.

Comment: what do you mean to give UILabel(B) constraint to trailing space right side?

Comment: mute logo give constraint to right side of stack view.