# Is there a way to make long strings wrap in addition to autoshrink?

Tags: ios, objective-c, styling

I have dynamic text in a label with plenty of room around it. Since there is room, it would be great if the text could wrap in addition to autoshrinking.

[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626548/how-to-make-uilabel-wordwrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply any of these 2 solutions

1.Set numberOfLines To 0 and make larger height of your label then text automatically wrap.

2.you can dynamically calculate height of label on the basis of length of string with function sizeWithFont.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have thought to set the number of lines to zero. But now that you point it out, I guess it was right in front of me. Works exactly like I need it to!