# How to make a UILabel dynamic?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make a UIlabel Wrap as many times as needed based on a comment text given to it?

I have tried many things like:

```
        self.commentText.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    self.commentText.numberOfLines = 0
//        self.commentText.leadingMargin(pixel: 10)
//        self.commentText.trailingMargin(pixel: 10)
```

Which I got from [[Qs like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626548/how-to-make-uilabel-wordwrap).] and [UILabel - auto-size label to fit text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796862/uilabel-auto-size-label-to-fit-text/8796896#8796896)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626548/how-to-make-uilabel-wordwrap)

But am not able to make the wrapping work

How I setup:

```
        private func setupTheCommentText() {
        self.commentText.frame = CGRect(x: 85, y: 35, width: 272, height: 15)
        self.commentText.textColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 92/255, blue: 92/255, alpha: 1)
        self.commentText.font = UIFont(name: "SFCompactDisplay-Medium", size: 13)
        //self.commentText.numberOfLines = 0
        //self.commentText.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        //self.commentText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        self.commentText.leadingMargin(pixel: 10)
//        self.commentText.trailingMargin(pixel: 10)
        self.addSubview(commentText)
        self.commentText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:username.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        commentText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.commentText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:username.bottomAnchor),
            self.commentText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.leadingAnchor,constant:85.0),
            self.commentText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.trailingAnchor,constant:-15.0),//,constant:-85.0
            self.commentText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:commentText.bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }
```

Comment: Have you given the label a fixed width? Show the code you are using to add the label to the view. Or show a screenshot of the storyboard and constraints.

Comment: From your edit you seem to be mixing up using frames and using auto layout constraints. You should use one or the other. You need to add the rest of the constraints to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give these constraints

> leading,trailing,top,bottom // bottom is for cells

```
commentText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  self.commentText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:username.bottomAnchor),
  self.commentText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.leadingAnchor,constant:85.0),
  self.commentText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.trailingAnchor,constant:-85.0),
  self.commentText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.bottomAnchor) // this for cells 
])
```

Above i assume it's inside a vc's view , if it's no the case and it's a cell replace `self.view` with `self.contentView`

Comment: I have tried many variations with this code and although the text is wrapping it now appears begging not x=85. how can I make it start from 85?

Comment: add `,constant:85.0` to the `leading/trailing` anchor see edit

Comment: To get closer to the intended result I did this: NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.commentText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:username.bottomAnchor),
            self.commentText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.leadingAnchor,constant:85.0),
            self.commentText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.trailingAnchor),//,constant:-85.0
            //self.commentText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.bottomAnchor) // this for cells
            ])

Comment: The issue is that how the label does not wrap

Comment: where it is table/collection ?

Comment: this code is inside the customTableView cell class, the tableView is inside a container which is inside a baseVC

Comment: Even if I do: self.contentView

Comment: Do `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before `return cell`